# How to install iwlwifi?

Tags: wifi

I have a new Carbon X1 and as a first step I try to install the wifi-driver. I checked arch and it says I need iwlwifi

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_5)

i googled it and found

https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

but first step doesn't work.

Can you give a brief summary to install the driver?

Regards
snowparrot

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; uname -r` as there isn't a way to give a good answer without that info.  The iwlwifi module is included in the kernel and most of the firmware is installed by default but there are a few new Intel wifi devices that don't have support in the 4.4 kernel

Comment: I just install the new Ubuntu hardware stack. It solved all problems!

Answer (score 1):

Used my iPhone to get a temporary Internet connection, and found this site:
http://www.edimax.com/edimax/download/download/data/edimax/global/download/for_home/wireless_adapters/wireless_adapters_ac1750_dual-band/ew-7833uac

Used the Linux drivers for my ASUS 1900 AC68 USB device and worked on the first try.  Before I updated the driver, I performed all of the OS updates through my iPhone, just in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Under elementary OS, to get `iwlwifi` working, you only have to install the `linux-firmware` and the `linux-image-extra-virtual` packages.

Answer (score 0):

I would just go to Software & Updates and look under Additional Drivers.  If you have a proprietary wifi driver, it will most likely be listed here.  This is probably the most stable way to do it.

Otherwise you can try these answers, since EOS is based on Ubuntu:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/608983/verisons-of-iwlwifi-and-firmware-for-my-wireless-card

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2305111